# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings vs Constants Class

Tags: c#, class, static, constants

If you have hard coded strings in your app, when should you store it in the App.Config file and when should you use a const string in a public static class?

I guess a benefit of using AppSettings is that you don't need to recompile like you would if you used a static class, are there any other pros/cons?

Comment: In AppSettings when it needs to change... often. Often is relative

Comment: is that because you don't need to recompile?

Comment: App config can be more useful in situations where you have environment specific (Dev vs Test vs Prod) changes too. You can then look at config transformations as part of your environment builds.

Comment: Yes, you wouldn't have to recompile or redeploy your application